# What are the characteristics of this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I need to replace this capacitor on the dynamo of my electric generator.

Beside being 20µF, what are the important characteristics that I should look for in a replacement?

[image]

Comment: Voltage, obviously.

Comment: Your cap snuffed it .The life spec of your dead cap is not that great .If your gear must run 24/7 then a longer life part is needed.

Comment: @Autistic Does the cap look trashed? I'm not sure my problem is due to the cap but the manufacturer of the electric generator advised me to start there as it's a very cheap component and it's easy to replace. In any case I ordered the cap and will give it a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a metallized polypropylene film capacitor in a plastic case of the type in [Farnell](http://cpc.farnell.com/1/1/19316-ducati-4-16-10-25-14-capacitor-20uf-450vac-lead.html) by the looks of it: -

[image]

If not the exact type (part numbers look very similar) then use the data sheet (also on the Farnell site) to home in on the exact part.

Comment: If it is indeed defective, you may want to consider a higher-voltage rated replacement if available François. Metallized film capacitors are typically quite rugged, so if this failed prematurely, a higher voltage rating should extend it's life. (But it will be physically larger.) Excessive heat will also cause premature failure; if it is located somewhere normally hot and can be relocated a very short distance somewhere cooler, that will also extend it's service life. (But avoid long leads as this will reduce it's efficiency, increase losses, and result in even more heat.)

Answer (score 1):

Hello Francois Beaune,

If you are looking to replace that capacitor, you need to know the maximum voltage rating of the capacitor, the amount of farads it stores. Also if you find a part no. on the capacitor you may be able to order the exact same piece or if not you can refer to its datasheet for more comprehensive information. A datasheet proves very valuable if you are replacing some component with other. You may also want to match the efficiency of the capacitors(optional).

Good Luck!